# How to scrape react state using javascript from browser console without react dev tools?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension

I am looking to find a way to capture/scrape react web app state's data from the browser console without using react dev tools.

Comment: why not use any of the available `console` methods in your code and simply log your state?

Comment: @tromgy I'm not the web app owner, I'm doing scrapping

Comment: React has an internal hook `window.__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__` which you should set in [page context](/a/9517879) at `document_start`. Read the source code of React Devtools to see how it configures the hook.